# How to determine whether an NSURL has security scope info?

Tags: macos, nsurl, appstore-sandbox

In earlier versions of macOS, `NSURL` instances constructed from a security-scoped bookmark would have an `?applesecurityscope=...` query string tagged onto the end of them. I was checking for this in a unit test, as it was a requirement of the function under test. Now, starting with 10.10 Yosemite, I can't find a way to determine from any public-facing property of an `NSURL` whether or not it has security scope.

There is no `query` or `parameterStrings` value, and `-startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` returns `YES` whether a URL has security scope or not.

This is especially useful to test for since my unit tests don't run in a sandboxed environment, but the app is, so the URLs the function produces must have security scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to obtain a security scoped bookmark from that url. This only works if the url is already security scoped and will fail for "regular" urls:

```
let isSecurityScoped = (try? url.bookmarkData(options: .withSecurityScope,
                               includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, 
                               relativeTo: nil)) != nil
```

Alternatively you can try calling `url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()`. This only succeeds if the url is security scoped.